# How to edit /etc/profile using emacs?

Tags: terminal, emacs, sudo

I am using [Emacs 24.3](http://emacsformacosx.com) on Mac OS X 10.9.4 and I am trying to edit `/etc/profile` with that. It obviously does not work when starting the GUI version, but for some reason, it also does not work when starting it with `sudo` from the command line. When I run

```
sudo emacs /etc/profile
```

from the terminal, Emacs still complains that the file is in read-only mode and it cannot write it:

```
Buffer is read-only: #<buffer profile>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/profile` is set to read-only for all users, so just using `sudo` won't help.

What you can do:

- run `sudo emacs /etc/profile`
- type `C-x C-q` to toggle readonly mode within Emacs
- edit whatever you want
- type `C-x C-s` to save it

Alternatively you can run

```
EDITOR=emacs sudo -e /etc/profile
```

which automatically creates a temporary copy of the file you want to edit (which makes it a bit safer in case you want to cancel the update).